# How to SSH from Amiga to remote Linux host

Tags: amiga, network, linux

With a new purchase coming in shortly I wanted to ask what do I need to be able to SSH to a remote host from an Amiga:

1. Make modem work and connect to my network:
   https://www.ebay.com/itm/KCWIFI-PRO-c64-plus4-c128-Amiga-Apple-II-PET-retro-rs232-modem-wifi-hayes-AT/154303064959?hash=item23ed2deb7f:g:4F8AAOSwfrleChLb
2. Install SSH client:
   http://amiga.sourceforge.net/?showpackage=OpenSSH
3. Configure? What how?

Seems like a daunting task considering I never done it before, but is my thinking correct? Did I miss anything or is there any gotchas to bear in mind?

Comment: I don't have experience with Amiga, but I've set up an SSH client on a DOS retro-machine and that looks right as long as the Amiga version of OpenSSH is modern enough to support one of the ciphers still on the SSH server's allowed list. (Like SSL/TLS, SSH prefs off ciphers as they become "no longer considered secure enough".) If it's anything like the Linux and DOS SSH clients, and the default ciphers on the server are OK, and you haven't restricted it to pubkey auth only on the server, then it should Just Work™ with no step 3.

Comment: If you find that you cannot make the Amiga connect directly to a host using ssh, or it may be too slow, you might consider having a small Linux box which the Amiga can telnet to, and then ssh from that box onwards.  Seen from the users point of view telnet and ssh are very similar.

Comment: The SSH packages listed behind the link are severely outdated: 3.7 3.8 3.9, dated 2003 and 2004. So outdated that they might not have common cipher (cf. @ssokolow comment) and/or moot security because of known bugs, see e.g. https://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list.php?vendor_id=97&product_id=585&cvssscoremin=7

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One thing you will certainly need: Patience, a lot of it. Establishing SSH connections with either the client or server side having a very low performance CPU (as in, an 68xxx. I once tried with the client on a Mac LCII with NetBSD...) can take several MINUTES to do all the key exchange work. Also, plan in half an hour for generating the keys when installing an SSH server on such a machine...

Since this probably on a network behind some kind of perimeter firewall (eg your DSL router) and for experimental/personal use - do feel justified to ignore best practices and use an unencrypted (telnet, rlogin, rsh...) connection for shell access.

Answer (score 3):

For configuration of SANA-II drivers for serial line interfaces see [Roadshow](http://roadshow.apc-tcp.de/index-en.php), "slip.device" is your friend.
Better use a newer [openssl](http://aminet.net/package/util/crypt/openssl) port because the encryption methods may be obsolete.